# Can't see items from one project in another C#

Tags: c#, reference, projects

I have all of my references set up, and the classes are public, but I still cannot see the classes and project in the project I'm working in.  Does anyone have any other ideas to try?  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you type the full path to the class or have added usings to the top of your file.

Comment: Have you added the reference for your project?

Comment: Make sure the .NET versions are compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be number of reasons for this.

1. Please Check If added the Reference Correctly to your project
2. Then Check your accessor methods in the referring project.make sure you use the `public` keyword for classes and methods you want to reference.
3. Bothe projects should be in same .NET version or Reference project should be less than the refereeing project
4. if you can show the specific code both projects it's easier to determine

Comment: To achieve that both projects be in the same . NET versions one possibility is to create Reference project by copy from the refereeing project.